# UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() crashes app distributed on devices ONLY

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I created a sample single page swift language based iOS app that CRASHES on this  func call in viewDidLoad() -

```
func regularFont() -> UIFont {
    var fontSize : CGFloat = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad) ? 15 : 12
    return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)
}
```

But once I replace this UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() with Apple recommended UIDevice() method, it WORKS fine.

```
func regularFont() -> UIFont {
    var fontSize : CGFloat = (UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad) ? 15 : 12
    return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)
}
```

The crash occurs on all devices I tested - iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPad Air (all on iOS 8.x) and it happens **ONLY on devices**, NOT simulator.

PS: The app is installed on all devices through our OTA/web link.

To my surprise, we have another objective c language based app on Apple's App Store that uses UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() heavily, regularly updated... but never crashed due to this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it (partially!). Actually "**release**" implementation of `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` in **swift** project crashes the app.

Once I **edit the scheme to "release"** (Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration change to "Release") and then run on simulator/device, the app crashes everywhere.. all devices/simulators/developer/distribution profiles.

However, still I have no clue why our app store app (objective c language based) does NOT crash.

My only guess is that it's a glitch in `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` API implementation with some language specific coding (swift vs objective c) by Apple.

Anyways, I would replace all `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` with `UIDevice(). userInterfaceIdiom`. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is just an Objective-C macro, which is defined as:

```
#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() \ ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? \ [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : \ UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

So when you work with Swift, you need to use as:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Unspecified
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Agree, we should use UIDevice var/property. But, just a little technical correction to your answer - it's NOT a macro but 'static inline' function defined in UIDevice.h and has func declaration in swift version of the class.

Comment: I owe you my sanity: today I compiled in release, instead of debug, for the first time and my app crashed so hard... and when I looked online for an answer, I found [this](http://openradar.appspot.com/21175489). The fact that is fixed in Xcode 7 beta 2 doesn't help me, since I want to launch next month... so, I know comments are not for thanks, but you saved my day!

Comment: ahh, you're welcome, bro. And you just make me had a good start for today.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.3 and up:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .pad {
  // do stuff
}
```